# What would happen if I use LoadLibraryExW() to load same .dll twitce when ASLR is on?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, dll

What would happen if I load same .dll twice or more times using:

```
handle = ::LoadLibraryExW(dllpath, NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH)
```

Does it return same address when ASLR(DYNAMICBASE) is on?

Comment: You can't load a DLL with the same name into memory more than once.  So the obvious thing happens, it simply increments the reference count and now two calls to FreeLibrary() are required to unload it again.  And you get the same HMODULE back.  Which happens to be the base address of the DLL on win32 and win64, an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing different than without ASLR. The second LoadLibraryEx call will return the same handle as the first call and the usage count of the DLL is incremented.

So the DLL isn't loaded "twice". Is is loaded on the first call.

Except the different use of the search path the behavior is identical to LoadLibrary.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx),

Section: Remarks [3rd Para]

> If the specified module is a DLL **that is not already loaded** for
>   the calling process, the system calls the DLL's DllMain function with
>   the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value.

[11th Para]

> **The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded
>   modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count.** Calling
>   the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the
>   reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count
>   reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the
>   reference count).

If the module is already loaded in the process memory, it will just return you back the same `HMODULE` handle with incremented reference count. Also, it will not call the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` in subsequent calls.